# cannot connect to ubuntu vm after commenting RSAAuthentication and PubkeyAuthentication

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I have made an Ubuntu vm on Azure to deploy blockchain poc made by Fabric and composer. Since it was my deployment environment, I need to connect to it from my development environment. I used Bitvise to ssh to it, but access was denied. I checked sshd_config in etc/ssh and added

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to it. When I tried again from Bitvise on my personal Windows it was again access denied. Since I didn't know what the cause of the problem was, I defined an outbound policy in windows firewall to allow port 22 be open and it was already open. After defining outbound rule again access was denied. I thought maybe it was because of company's firewall, and therefore, in Azure made another Ubuntu vm just to check if it can ssh my deployment vm. It couldn't. I tried:

```
ssh -vvv 52.136.*.*
```

and read the more verbose message an it was written it needed publickey and password and it failed. I am sure my password is correct as I have changed it by both:

```
passwd
```

and

```
sudo passwd
```

After seeing the message from Azure bash I did ssh to my vm, the one which is my development environment, and commented sshd_config in etc/ssh the two following lines:

```
#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I also made my both VMs' IPs static and in my first vm, the problematic one, the one for deployment that I am trying to ssh, made the following change in sshd_config:

```
Match address <public IP  of my second vm>
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

After that I cannot connect to my VM in anyway not even Azure bash terminal!!!

It gives the error:

```
ssh: connect to host: 52.13*.*.* port 22: connected refused.
```

And here is the verbose error:

[image]

Is there a way to make my server again workable. I cannot even connect to it. I have always this issue that I cannot ssh from my local machine to my VM on Azure and trying to configure sshd_config causes more mess.Any help in both is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not add `Match address <public IP  of my second vm>` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. You could check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101670/how-can-i-allow-ssh-password-authentication-from-only-certain-ip-addresses), the IP is source IP.

Now, you could rest sshd configuration on Azure Portal, then you could ssh your VM again.

[image]